# How to bind applications to specific network adapter

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet, bind

I am currently using a computer in a corporate environment which is connected to the intranet through the ethernet adapter and to the internet through the wireless adapter.

The problem is this: the ethernet adapter has higher priority in the routing table, so if the wire is connected to the ethernet adapter I cannot neither access the internet nor get emails in Outlook.

I am wondering if it is possible to bind, for instance, Internet Explorer to the ethernet adapter so I can access to the intranet and Chrome and Outlook to the wireless adapter so I can both surfer the internet and get emails when the wire is connected.

I have already tried ForceBindIP but I cannot get it working on Windows 7 64 bits.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks,
Bralok

Comment: Why does it matter that ethernet takes priority? Ethernet is faster? Are these two networks different networks altogether? If so, bridging the two networks is a bad idea from a few standpoints. One being security.

Comment: Your problems are caused by a wrongly configured routing table. You have to define a default gateway and set up the routes and maybe additional gateways for specific hosts or nets. If that is set up correctly, you don't have to worry about which NIC to use for this or that application.

Comment: Thank you Robert for your quick response. I have 2 concerns about your solution:

1.- I have to access several domains within the intranet because my company is a big group with locations in several contries all around the world. So every time I need to access a new domain I should include a new route in the routing table, shouldn't I?

2.- As I said in #1, I access several domains within the intranet via URL. Can you please let me know an easy way of getting the IP Address/subnet to get it configured?


Thanks again!

Comment: @Bralok In order to get a detailed answer, you should provide your routing table and the output of ipconfig.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this solution using the following:

1. comodo firewall(free)
2. forcebindip (free)

assumptions:
1. LAN is the corporate network own ip and gateway
2. Wireless is the one that you want to use it
3. chrome is the browser for use JUST with wireless network card

install comodo firewall and create 3 rules for chrome application in this way:
1. go to firewall then application rules, then add , select the path of the chrome and then use the option "USE the custom rule set"

**rule 1 ALLOW IP through wireless network card
action: allow
protocol: IP
direction : in or out
Description: Just wireless

Source address: - MAC ADDRESS
MAc Address :

Destination address : any

IP details : any

**rule 2 ALLOW protocol through wireless network card
action: allow
protocol: TCO or UDP
direction : in or out
Description: Enable tragic wireless

Type: - Network Zone
Zone: Wireless network Connection

Destination address : any

Source port: any

Destination port  : any

**rule 3 Block traffic through LAN network card
action: Bloc
protocol: TCO or UDP
direction : in or out
Description: BLOCK trafic LAN

Type: - Network Zone
Zone: Local Area Connection

Destination address : any

Source port: any

Destination port  : any

we are almost done. open your IE and chrome at the same time, you will notice the navigation is blocked in your chrome.

Now install the forcebindip  that small program use 2 file , the executable and the BindIP.dll, the dll goes to windows\system32 (32bit OS) and windows\system32 and windows\syswow64 for 64 bits.

now create 2 separate batch files
first one for execute the forcebind and the second execute the first one with elevated 
permissions

batch 1: (execute the second bath as admin) 
"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -windowstyle hidden -nologo -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -command "start-process -verb 'runas' -filepath

batch 2: (Launch chrome incognito mode and open automatically a page to check the WAN IP) 
C:\Windows\System32\ForceBindIP.exe XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --incognito --new-window http://ip-lookup.net/index.php

XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX: replace the X´s with the local ip of your wireless card. , if you are using DHCP on this interface you need to update the bath every time.

enjoy
Note:

Answer (score 0):

Regarding ForceBindIP you could try to contact the developer and ask him to provide a 64 bit version. As it seems you are not alone with the desire for a 64 bit version.

In your case I would use the default network config for the LAN link and a static IP without DNS and without default gateway for the wireless network. That way you are sure that you will not have problems with the corporate network.

You could do all browsing with IE using direct link to intranet sites and proxy to external sites. For some limited IPs like for mail (or a second browser without proxy configured) you could add entries to the routing table. Let's assume the IP of your wireless router is 192.168.178.1. Then you could `nslookup mailserver.for.outlook`. You can then add that IP address to the routing table with `route add <ip-of-mail-server> mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.178.1`. The option `-p` after `add` will add the route persistently until you delete it with `route delete <ip-of-mail-server>`.

You can check which route Windows is using with `tracert <ip>`. This should show you the wireless router as the first router used.